# How is {0}, {1}, etc., called in C#?

Tags: c#, string

In this code:

> Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}", name);

How is this {0} called?

I'm starting in C# and I've seen some codes with this.

I kind of know how it works, but why should I use `("Hello {0}", name)` instead of `("Hello " + name)`?

Comment: [Console.WriteLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netcore-3.1) [Composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting)

Comment: You can also do `$"Hello {name}"`.  That said, `string.Concat` is faster than `string.Format`, which is what you are comparing.

Comment: You can also format strings directly - `Console.WriteLine("Hello {0:0.00}", 3.14159)` will write out `Hello 3.14`.

Comment: `{0}` is called [Composite Formatting][1]:  whereas the `$` method is called [String Interpoation][2]   Take a look at the documentation if you want to see all the variety of ways you can use these options.  IMO, you will end up using composite formatting quite a bit.


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting
  [2]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: Ok, guys, got it! Thanks for the answers, they were all really helpful!

Comment: Also, if you have many parameters to be printed the code becomes very hard to read if formatted like "hello " + name + " " + address + andSoOn... The string interpolation provided in answers is the most readable way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the following is the Format args pattern which is similar to `String.Format`

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}", name)

// or

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Hello {0}", name));
```

if you look at the *source code* to this *overload* of `WriteLine`, you will find  actually it calls `String.Format`

```
WriteLine(string.Format(FormatProvider, format, arg0));
```

You could however use

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello " + name)
```

There is no real difference <sup>1</sup>, however you miss out on all the extra format abilities of `String.Format` (though in your case you are not using any of them anyway)

You could also use the more modern *string interpolation*

```
Console.WriteLine($"Hello {name}")
```

As to what you want to use, depends on what you need to do, and what you are comfortable with. All have their advantages and disadvantages

---

**Further reading**

[$ - string interpolation (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

[String.Format Method](http://v)

---

<sup>1</sup> As noted by [@Zero](http://Zer0) `String.Format` actually does a lot internally, so it's slower.

Comment: "There is no real difference".  Functionally, no.  Performance wise, yes.  `string.Format` is measurably slower.  Whether such a [relatively] small hit matters depends on the code.

Comment: @Zer0 updated and attributed, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is called string interpolation. Below is a useful reference

https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/02/06/performance-of-string-concatenation-in-c/